# Split the filename with multiple occurence

Tags: split, terraform

Trying to split file name into multiple variables with Delimiter

Filename example :
dimitri.weqn_good-read.sky.txt
yuan.tagine_sold-v1-write.ground.pdf

Expected

```
{
type = txt 
trans = sky
operation = read
rest = dimitri.weqn_good
},
{
type = pdf 
trans = ground 
operation = write 
rest = yuan.tagine_sold-v1
```

Tried with this

```
operation = write
rest = ${split("-", file)[0]}
```

this is failing with multiple delimeters "-"

actual

rest = "yuan.tagine_sold"

expected = "yuan.tagine_sold-v1"

Comment: Well, it's splitting at the hyphen so that's how it is supposed to work, because a string `yuan.tagine_sold-v1` will be split into `yuan-tangine_sold` and `v1`. Underscore is not the same as hyphen.

Comment: Yes, if have multiple delimiters, file name structure is unknown so in those cases, I need consider only last and ignore other occurences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use regular expressions:

```
locals{

    filename = ["dimitri.weqn_good-read.sky.txt", 
               "yuan.tagine_sold-v1-write.ground.pdf"]
              
   splitted = [
     for filename in local.filename: {
      type = regex(".+\\.(.+)$", filename)[0]
      trans = regex(".+\\.(.+)\\..+$", filename)[0]
      operation = regex(".+-([[:alpha:]]+)\\.", filename)[0]
      rest = regex("^(.+)\\-(.+)",filename)[0]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for regex, was looking for "rest" variable to parse last occurrence "-"  to get output and ignore other '-"

Comment: @Nabob So why not edit my question or give me chance to edit it? Its better then copping my answer, adding minute edits, and posting it as your own answer.

Comment: Agreed, Tried to do same first. it says "too many pending edits" on your answer